# Dependency Injection: Field Injection vs Constructor Injection?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, java-ee

I know this is a hot debate and the opinions tend to change over time as to the best approach practice.

I used to use exclusively field injection for my classes, until I started reading up on different blogs (exs: [petrikainulainen](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/software-development/design/why-i-changed-my-mind-about-field-injection/) and [schauderhaft](http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2012/01/01/the-one-correct-way-to-do-dependency-injection/#comment-2825180814) and [fowler](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)) about the benefits of constructor injection.  I have since switched my methodologies to use constructor injection for required dependencies and setter injection for optional dependencies.

However, [I have recently gotten into a debate](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jmockit-users/BVKhCcXAqJY/d4XVFgd-AgAJ) with the author of JMockit - a mocking framework - in which he sees constructor & setter injection as bad practice and indicates that the JEE community agrees with him.

In today's world, is there a preferred way of doing injection?  Is Field injection preferred?

Having switched to constructor inject from field injection in the last couple of years, I find it a lot clearer to use, but I am wondering if I should re-examine my viewpoint.  The author of [JMockit (Rogério Liesenfeld)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2326914/rog%C3%A9rio), is clearly well versed in DI, so I feel obligated to review my approach given that he feels so strongly against constructor/setter injection.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/266953/31260

Comment: @gnat Does the concept/response change in the context of dependency injection though?  Or is the pattern still respected?

Comment: If you're not allowed to use constructor injection ***or*** setter injection, then how are you supposed to hand your dependencies to the class?  Maybe you'd better link to the debate, unless your conversation with the Mockit guy was private.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I've updated the question with a link to the google groups thread.  I abandoned pursuing the issue with him but I'm still looking for support for his arguments.  If I can find enough evidence that field injection is good/preferable over constructor and/or setter, I'm open to modifying my ways.  Otherwise, I feel I'm regressing in development practices.

Comment: There is a modern line of thought that says a class either should contain (ideally immutable) state or functionality. In such situations, it becomes that case that both constructor and property injection are inappropriate as both are only needed when data and functionality are mixed. In this situation, injecting data and other method references into methods becomes the only "acceptable" form of injection. This comes about in no small part due to the growth in popularity of functional languages, where this approach is baked into the language.

Comment: @DavidArno - I'm not sure I fully understand the subtlety of state vs functionality.  Wouldn't a state class be essentially an Enum?  I would think that anything that implements functionality would have some stateness to it...  Are there any references where I can read more about that line of thought?

Comment: @DavidArno: In an immutable class, the state is set once... in the *constructor.*

Comment: @Davkd what you're describing is the anemic domain model. It certainly has proponents but it is not really object orientated any more; where data and the functons that act on that data live together.

Comment: @RichardTingle, who says anything has to be object orientated? Most modern "OO" languages can be used to write functional-orientated code too. It's certainly not anaemic or academic; functional solutions can, and have, been applied to many real-world problems.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, this is true; however *injection*, in the sense that the OP is referring to, tends to refer to `dependency injection`. Values injected into an immutable value object aren't dependencies.

Comment: @EricB. take a look at http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/c-program-entirely-with-static-methods.html. It uses C#, but the same principles can be applied to Java 8.

Comment: @David There's nothing wrong with functional programming. But java fundamentally is designed to be object orientated and you will constantly be fighting it and end up with [the anemic domain model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) if you're not very careful . There's nothing wrong with function orientated code but an appropriate tool should be used for it, which java isn't (even though lambda's have added elements of function based programming)

Comment: @RichardTingle, interesting historical article that very much reflects people's thinking 12 years ago. It was a reaction to people writing procedural style code using OO semantics. Ironically, history has shown us that this "anemic domain model" was close, but not quite there, to an arguably better way of doing things.

Comment: @DavidArno Interesting blog.  I've also been noticing a lot recently that stateless design is a lot like static methods/functional design rather than true OOP.

Comment: This argument is about the same as whether we should make all methods public just so they are easier to unit test. No, just no. Darned unit testing fanatics....

Comment: @DavidArno - you seem to be making the common error of thinking that "functional programming" is the converse of "object-oriented programming". It is not. Functional code **can** be object-oriented, with immutable objects. The converse of "functional programming" is "imperative programming", which is the style most of us have been used to. The "functional" in "functional programming" does not come from programming functions. It comes from mathematical functions. Functional code is like a set of (the mathematical kind of) functions, not a sequence of steps executed as in imperative programs.

Comment: https://blog.marcnuri.com/field-injection-is-not-recommended/

Answer (score 54):

Field injection is a bit too *"spooky action at a distance"* for my taste.

Consider the example you provided in your Google Groups post:

```
public class VeracodeServiceImplTest {


    @Tested(fullyInitialized=true)
    VeracodeServiceImpl veracodeService;
    @Tested(fullyInitialized=true, availableDuringSetup=true)
    VeracodeRepositoryImpl veracodeRepository;
    @Injectable private ResultsAPIWrapper resultsApiWrapper;
    @Injectable private AdminAPIWrapper adminApiWrapper;
    @Injectable private UploadAPIWrapper uploadApiWrapper;
    @Injectable private MitigationAPIWrapper mitigationApiWrapper;

    static { VeracodeRepositoryImpl.class.getName(); }
...
}
```

So basically what you are saying is that  "I have this class with private state, to which I have attached `@injectable` annotations, which means that the state can be automagically populated by some agent from the outside, even though my state has all been declared *private.*"

I understand the motivations for this.  It is an attempt to avoid much of the ceremony that is inherent in setting up a class properly.  Basically, what one is saying is that "I'm tired of writing all of this boilerplate, so I'm just going to annotate all of my state, and let the DI container take care of setting it for me."

It's a perfectly valid point of view.  But it's also a workaround for language features that arguably should not be worked around.  Also, why stop there?  Traditionally, DI has relied on each class having a companion Interface.  Why not eliminate all those interfaces with annotations as well?

Consider the alternative (this is going to be C#, because I know it better, but there's probably an exact equivalent in Java):

```
public class VeracodeService
{        
    private readonly IResultsAPIWrapper _resultsApiWrapper;
    private readonly IAdminAPIWrapper _adminApiWrapper;
    private readonly IUploadAPIWrapper _uploadApiWrapper;
    private readonly IMitigationAPIWrapper _mitigationApiWrapper;

    // Constructor
    public VeracodeService(IResultsAPIWrapper resultsApiWrapper, IAdminAPIWrapper adminApiWrapper, IUploadAPIWrapper uploadApiWrapper,         IMitigationAPIWrapper mitigationApiWrapper)
    {
         _resultsAPIWrapper = resultsAPIWrapper;
         _adminAPIWrapper = adminAPIWrapper;
         _uploadAPIWrapper = uploadAPIWrapper;
         _mitigationAPIWrapper = mitigationAPIWrapper;
    }
}
```

Already I know some things about this class.  It's an immutable class; state can only be set in the constructor (references, in this particular case).  And because everything derives from an interface, I can swap out implementations in the constructor, which is where your mocks come in.

Now all my DI container has to do is reflect over the constructor to determine what objects it needs to new up.  But that reflection is being done on a *public member,* in a first-class way; i.e. the metadata is already part of the class, having been declared in the constructor, *a method whose express purpose is to provide the class with the dependencies it needs.*

Granted this is a lot of boilerplate, but this is how the language was designed.  Annotations seem like a dirty hack for something that should have been built into the language itself.

Comment: Unless I read your post wrong, you are not actually looking at the example properly.  My implementation of `VeracodeService` is nearly identical to the one you wrote (albeit in Java vs C#).  The `VeracodeServiceImplTest` is actually a Unit Test class.  The `@Injectable` fields are essentially mocked objects  being inserted into the context.  The `@Tested` field is the object/class with the DI Constructor defined.  I agree with your viewpoint that prefers Constructor injection over field injection.  However, as I mentioned, the JMockit author feels the opposite and I am trying to understand why

Comment: If you look at the [first post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jmockit-users/BVKhCcXAqJY/w1h1FNx1AgAJ) in that discussion you'll see I have almost the exact same defn in my Repo class.

Comment: If you're only talking about test classes, it may not matter.  Because, test classes.

Comment: No - I'm not talking about test classes.  I'm talking about production classes.  It just happens that the example in the discussion group is a unit test, since the framework is a mocking/testing framework.  (The whole discussion revolves around if the mocking framework should support constructor injection)

Comment: +1: Yes, no magic in the C# version. It's a standard class, it has dependencies, they're all injected at one point, before the class is used. The class can be used with a D I container, or not. Nothing in the class says it IOC or "Automatic Dependency Injection" framework.

Answer (score 33):

The argument of less test initialization boiletplate is valid, but there are other concerns that must be taken into account. First of all, you have to answer a question:

**Do I want my class to be instantiable only with reflection?**

Using field injections means narrowing down [compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_incompatibility) of a class to dependency injection environments that instantiate objects using reflection and support these particular injection annotations. Some platforms based on Java language do not even support reflection ([GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/)), so field‑injected class will not be compatible with them.

Second issue is [performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_performance). A constructor call (direct or by reflection) is always faster than a bunch of reflection field assignments. Dependency injection frameworks must use reflection analysis to build dependency tree and create reflection constructors. This process causes additional performance hit.

Performance affects [maintainability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintainability). If each test suite must be run in some sort of dependency injection container, a test run of few thousands unit tests may last tens of minutes. Depending of size of a code base, this may be an issue.

This all rises many new questions:

1. **What is the probability of using parts of the code on another platform?**
2. **How many unit tests will be written?**
3. **How fast do I need to prepare each new release?**
4. ...

Generally, the bigger and more important a project is, the more significant these factors are. Also, Quality-wise, we would generally like to the keep the code high on compatiblity, testability and maintainability. From the philosophical point of view, field injection breaks [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)), which is one of four fundamentals of [object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), which is the main paradigm of Java.

Many, many arguments against field injection.

Comment: +1 You hit a nerve. I don't like needing reflection or a DI/IoC framework to instantiate a class. It's like driving to Rome to get to Paris from Amsterdam. Mind you I love DI. Just not sure about the frameworks.

Comment: Great arguments.  It verbalizes a lot of the thoughts I had myself but I am happy to see others feeling the same way.  As amazing as I used to find field injection, I think I loved it so much simply because it was "easier".  I find constructor injection so much clearer now.

Comment: In one of the projects, I had all classes being autowired by field injection. I changed them all to constructor injection. The application was taking more time or equal time to start. So I would say that there is no performance gain for constructor DI over field DI.

Comment: You would need to create a micro-benchmark that does only constructor injections and field injections in order to acurately state something like that.

Answer (score 23):

Field injection gets a definite "No" vote from me.

Like Robert Harvey, it is a bit too automagic for my taste. I prefer explicit code over implicit, and tolerate indirection only as/when it provides clear benefits as it makes code harder to understand and reason about.

Like Maciej Chałapuk, I don't like needing reflection or a DI/IoC framework to instantiate a class. It's like driving to Rome to get to Paris from Amsterdam.

Mind you I love DI and all the advantages it brings. Just not sure about needing the frameworks to instantiate a class. Especially not the effect that IoC containers or other DI frameworks can have on test code.

I like my tests to be very straightforward. I don't like having to go through the indirection of setting up an IoC containers or other DI framework to then have them set up my class under test. It just feels awkward.

And it makes my tests dependent on the global state of the framework. That is to say that I can no longer run two tests in parallel that require an instance of class X to be set up with different dependencies.

At least with constructor and setter injection, you have the option of not using the frameworks and/or reflection in your tests.

Comment: If you use, for instance, Mockito http://mockito.org/ , you don't need a DI/IoC framework even when using field injection, and can run test in parallel and so forth.

Comment: @hstoerr Nice. However, that must mean that Mockito is using reflection (or whatever the Java equivalent of that is called)...

Answer (score 10):

Well, this seems a polemic discussion. The first thing that needs to be addressed is that **Field injection is different from Setter injection**. I already work with some people that thinks Field and Setter injection is the same thing.

So, to be clear:

Field injection:

```
@Autowired
private SomeService someService;
```

Setter injection:

```
@Autowired
public void setSomeService(SomeService someService) {
    this.someService = someService;
}
```

But, for me, both share the same concerns.

And, my favorite, the constructor injection:

```
@AutoWired
public MyService(SomeService someService) {
    this.someService = someService;
}
```

I have the follow reasons to believe that the constructor injection is better than setter/field injection (I will quote some Spring links to demonstrate my point):

1. **Prevent circular dependencies**: Spring is able to detect circular dependencies between the Beans, as @Tomasz explained. See also the [Spring Team saying](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#d0e2778) that.
2. **Dependencies of the class are obvious**: The dependencies of the class [are obvious in the constructor](http://blog.indrek.io/articles/to-field-inject-or-not-to/) but **hided** with field/setter injection. I feel my classes like a "black box" with field/setter injection. And there is (by my experience) a tendency to developers not bother about the class with many dependencies, that is obvious when you try to mock the class using constructor injection (see the next item). A problem that bothers the developers is most likely to be resolved. Also, a class with too many dependencies probably violate the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP).
3. **Easy and reliable to mock**: [compared to Field injection](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/), it's easier to mock in a unit test, because you don't need any context mock or reflection technic to reach the declared private Bean inside the class and you will not be [fooled by it](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/). You just instantiate the class and pass the mocked beans. Simple to understand and easy.
4. **Code quality tools can help you**: Tools like Sonar can warn you about the class getting too complex, because a class with a lot of parameters is probably a too complex class and need some refactor. This tools can't identify the same problem when the class is using Field/Setter injection.
5. **Better and independent code**: With less `@AutoWired` spread among your code, your code is less dependent of the framework. I know that the possibility to simple change the DI framework in a project not justify that (who does that, right?). But this shows, for me, a better code (I learned this in a [hard way](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) with EJB and lookups). And with Spring you can even remove the `@AutoWired` annotation using constructor injection.
6. **More annotations is not always the right answer**: [For](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1675634/2387977) some [reasons](https://www.yegor256.com/2016/04/12/java-annotations-are-evil.html), I really try to use annotations only when they are really useful.
7. **You can make the injections immutable**. The immutability is a [very welcomed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34385684/2387977) feature.

If you are looking for more information, I recommend [this old (but still relevant) article](http://spring.io/blog/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required) from Spring Blog telling us why they use so much setter injection and the recommendation to use constructor injection:

> setter injection is used a lot more often than you would expect, is
>   the fact that frameworks like Spring in general, are much more suited
>   to be configured by setter injection than by constructor injection

And this note about why they believe that constructor is more suitable for application code:

> I think constructor injection is much more usable for application code
>   than it is for framework code. In application code, you inherently
>   have a lesser need for optional values that you need to configure

## Final thoughts

If your are not really sure about the advantage of constructor, maybe the idea to mix setter (not field) with constructor injection is an option, as explained by the [Spring team](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#d0e2778):

> Since you can mix both, Constructor- and Setter-based DI, it is a good
>   rule of thumb to use constructor arguments for mandatory dependencies
>   and setters for optional dependencies

But remember the field injection is, probably, the one [to be avoided](http://vojtechruzicka.com/field-dependency-injection-considered-harmful/) among the three.